# How to make HashMap with an object as value, which again have it's own HashMap of objects. Java

Tags: java, object, hashmap

I have been working on this problem for quite some time now, searching around the internet to see if there was any answers, but to no luck unfortunately.

As the title says I am trying to make a `HashMap` which uses an `Object` (another class) as a value. Then, I want that `Object`, to hold another `HashMap` inside it self which also uses another `Object` as a value.

Here is how I would have done it:

**BookAdmin.java**

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class BookAdmin
{
    private static HashMap<String, Customer> customer = new Customer<String, Customer>();

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        customer.put("James", new Customer("James"));
        customer.put("Peter", new Customer("Peter"));

        customer.get("James").newBook("Flying 101");

        customer.get("James").seeBooks();
    }
}
```

**Customer.java**

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Customer
{
    private static HashMap<String, Book> book = new Book<String, Book>();
    private static String name = "";

    public Customer (String nameIn)
    {
        name = nameIn;
    }

    public void newBook (String title)
    {
        book.put(title, new Book(title));
    }

    public void seeBooks()
    {
        for (String l: book.keySet())
        {
            System.out.println(book.get(l).toString());
        }
    }
}
```

**Book.java**

```
public class Book
{
    private static String title = "";

    public Book (String titleIn)
    {
        title = titleIn;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
         return title;
    }
}
```

So it would seem to be pretty alright, but if I check "Peter"'s books too, it shows that he too owns "Flying 101". It's like they share the same book hashmap.

Comment: Hey there @fabian. I really like the effort you're putting into making these questions look nice and all, but I'd really appreciate if you could also purge greetings and similar fluff from posts as discussed [on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause for that issue is that you maintain your map in a static context. This means the map is **shared across all instances** of a class, see also [JLS 8.3.1.1. - static Fields](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.1)

> If a field is declared static, there exists exactly one incarnation of
>   the field, no matter how many instances (possibly zero) of the class
>   may eventually be created.

So when you say "It's like they share the same book hashmap.", that is because they actually do :)

Remove all the static modifiers from the posted code and you should be good to go

Comment: This is great Vogel! Thanks! Didn't know that, I am still kinda new.

But I am also wondering if there would be a way for me to not have a static HashMap in BookAdmin.java. 
So I could use the HashMap in other methods within BookAdmin.java - And have more instances of it (more unique customers).

Comment: @Jalokoh yes that should be possible. Be aware that main is required to be static and that you can only access the static context from main anyways. This means your BookAdmin class shouild remain unchanged (contrary to what my answer says)

Comment: Hm okay. But would that mean that all the keys in HashMap customer share the same Customer object? Since it remains static?

Comment: @Jalokoh you're mixing things up here. Just because the Map is static that doesnt't mean it's content objects are. The `new` Keyword you are using creates separate instances already

Comment: Oh okay! Now the program finally worked! I am super grateful! And I learned something new!